# PDO returning results, best way to store and output?

Tags: php, arrays, pdo

I'm looking to return an array from a PDO, and then output the results in a table.

I'm currently unsure of the correct way of going about this, as PDO has many different return methods (fetch, fetchAll, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) but to name a few, so please feel free to make suitable suggestions. I'm currently using fetch() with PDO::FETCH_ASSOC.

My current markup returns more than two rows, **and I need to output these into a visual table, selecting only a few of the columns returned in the array to actually display to the user**.

I have tried a foreach loop

```
 foreach ($object->getMethod() as $row)
```

however this obviously outputs everything, using $row['DB_COLUMN_NAME'] just returns the first letter of the data too?

Any suggestions on how to approach this?

**Application needs:**
MVC style framework, controller calling model method and passing variable for database query.
Model returning array (with result type open to suggestion).
View receives array, and needs to iterate through the returned rows, outputting them in a visual table (but only showing columns specified)

I can also create a new class in the controller too, if this is a better method.

Many thanks.

Comment: Hint: you're focusing your energy in the wrong place.

Comment: As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&A format. We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion. If you feel that this question can be improved and possibly not be closed, see the FAQ for guidance.

Comment: Sorry, it's been a long day. Updated question above. Thanks.

Comment: Not quite sure why this has been closed, or what further information I can provide?

Answer (score 3):

The answer depends on you.

- Use `fetch` in conjunction with a loop to iterate the rows and process each one at a time.
- Use `fetchAll` in order to dump the entire resultset into a variable (be it an array or an Object).

As for fetch modes:

- Use `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` to fetch an associative array, with the column names (or aliases) as keys.
- Use `PDO::FETCH_NUMERIC` to fetch a numeric array, with no column names but numbered indexes.
- Use `PDO::FETCH_BOTH` to fetch an array with duplicate entries, both associative and numeric in the same array.
- Use `PDO::FETCH_OBJECT` to fetch the data into an object (which should be tailored fit to the results you're expecting).

The ones you choose to use depend on your application needs. We cannot help you with that.

Comment: I have added my specific application needs above, if it helps with your answer at all. Many Thanks.